# What is wrong with myinit class here and how do i correct it?

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to create a game where you have a bunch of pancakes and you move them around. I have been trying to create a sprite class for my pancakes for quite some time, and I keep ending up with this error in Pycharm.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

num = 3


class cake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_y, width):  # pos_y -> int
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Pancake.png').convert_alpha()
        self.pancake = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, ([width], 80))
        self.rect = self.pancake.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = (750, [pos_y])


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pancake House')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.Surface((2000, 1000))
background.fill('#96e2fc')

# pancake = pygame.image.load("Pancake.png").convert_alpha()
# pancake = pygame.transform.scale(pancake,(200,80))
# pancake_rect = pancake.get_rect(midbottom = (750,550))

pancake = cake(550, 200)
pancakes = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
pancakes.add(pancake)

pygame.init()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    # screen.blit(pancake, pancake_rect)
    pancakes.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Am I not writing classes properly? Or is my Python syntax wrong?

I tried to look through existing questions and the documents, but I still couldn't figure it out. If this question is repetitive, then please direct me to the one that has the answer.

Comment: Can you post the error. The question looks incomplete

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your init function definition in line

```
def __int__(self, pos_y, width):
```

-> Function needs to be called `__init__` not `__int__`

Comment: i have corrected the typo and it still doesnt help. i am able to get one variable from the user and create an object but as soon as i try to get the pos_y value, the __init___() class stops being highlighted because i am giving wrong inputs or something.

Comment: ok i have got it to work now. the init next to the super still stops getting highlighted but my code works and i am able to use more variables so i thing it is fine. but any comments make this better are welcome